# Rails & Devise Mapping Path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm receiving the following error when trying to go to http://app.mysite.dev/login -

```
Could not find devise mapping for path "/login".
This may happen for two reasons:

1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example:

  devise_scope :user do
    get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"
  end

2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router.
   If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use:

   @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
```

Now, here is the relevant bits of my routes.rb file:

```
namespace 'app', path: '', constraints: { subdomain: 'app' } do
    devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations, :confirmations]
    devise_for :agents, :skip => :sessions

    devise_scope :users do
      get "login" => "users/sessions#new"
    end
    ...
end
```

And the route generated by the `get "login"` line is as follows (from `rake routes`)

```
app_login GET    /login(.:format)     app/users/sessions#new {:subdomain=>"app"}
```

I don't know if it matters, but I'm using STI for Users > Agents relationship.

So, I already am defining the scope for devise, and I'm not testing, so any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Can you show us your ``App::SessionsController``?

Comment: I don't have one - I'm assuming that is coming from Devise..

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your devise_scope with the following instead. Within your namespace 'app' block.

```
devise_scope :app_user do
  get "login" => "users/sessions#new"
end
```

It appears to be devise was changing the scope it was looking for within a namespace.

For your reference:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2496

And yeah, it should be `devise_scope :app_user` instead of `devise_scope :app_users`

Answer (score 1):

It's just a simple typo - `devise_scope :users` should be `devise_scope :user`, as stated in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't define a custom `SessionsController`for your `:users`, and `Devise` cannot use it's default one since you namespaced your `devise_scope :users`.

I'd define your own custom `class App::SessionsController` and then add it rewrite your routes like this:

```
namespace 'app', path: '', constraints: { subdomain: 'app' } do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'sessions' }, skip: [:registrations, :confirmations]

  devise_scope :users do
    get "login" => "sessions#new"
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you also mean for `App::SessionsController` to inherit from `Devise::SessionsController`? If I do that then I get the same problem as before, and if I don't surely I loose the use of Devise in those sessions?

Comment: You need to inherit from ``Devise::SessionsController`` of course. Look at de Devise docs for further reference if needed. If you define an ``App::SessionsController``, and your ``get "login" => "sessions#new"`` route is namespaced with ``app``, you should be able to get that route right. Can you show me the ``rake routes`` output in that case?

Comment: So, inheriting from `Devise::SessionsController` simply produces the same error I was receiving before, the only difference being that I don't now need to do the `get "login" => "sessions#new"` within the `devise_scope :users` block.
The rake routes for the login is `app_login GET    /login(.:format)                   app/sessions#new {:subdomain=>"app"}`